# Run command prompt from java?

Tags: java, command-line

Hi i want to run something from command prompt using java

i want to go to the following directory `C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program\`
and then run 
`soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard`

i tried but i am not able to do that!

my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");

           // Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");

            Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program\\soffice", 
                    "-headless",
                    "-accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;'",
                    "-nofirststartwizard"});

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? It's possible that soffice is not in you system path.

Comment: please post the *minimum complete* code that exhibits the problem behavior, and also post the stacktrace.

Comment: @joekarl Exited with error code 0

Comment: @jcomeau-ictx na its there when i run it diretely from my comman prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i solved it

```
String[] SOFFICE_CMD = { "C:/Program Files/OpenOffice.org 3/program/soffice", "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager", "-invisible", "-nologo"}; 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SOFFICE_CMD);
```

Thank u all for supporting!!

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `cd`, and use the string array method:

```
rt.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program\\soffice.exe", 
    "-headless",
    "-accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;'",
    "-nofirststartwizard"});
```

Comment: can i first change the directory and then run "soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard"

Comment: No you can't change the directory first

Comment: @Harinder I updated the answer to include `.exe`, could you try again with this new line? By the way you can not and do not need to use `cd` here.

Answer (score 2):

@Harinder : I would like to suggest an alternative method. What u can do is ;

1. First try to run whatever u want to run from the command prompt directly with all attributes etc. Once u have successfully run the service/application from the command prompt directly do 2.
2. Go and save the command in a .bat file.

For example: C:\m-admin\app.exe I saved this as app.bat on C:\

1. Now modify ur java code accordingly to execute this script which will in turn execute ur application or service.

For example:

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","C:\\app.bat"});
 Process pr =   builder.start();
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
```

1. if even this does not work ...we need to start from scratch again.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the code(below) using the process builder method. See if this works for you. Using exec sometimes does not work due to access violations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");

       // Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
       ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program", "soffice",
        "-headless",
        "-accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;'",
        "-nofirststartwizard"});
       Process pr =   builder.start();
       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));


        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i want C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program\\ to be my directory when i run soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found your mistake: change your argument to the following: See if it works:

```
(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program\\soffice",
            "-headless",
            "-accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;'",
            "-nofirststartwizard"})
```

Comment: I think u was correct about changing the directory first. See the above code again...I made some edits to the original thing i posted...

Comment: @Harinder : I am making my last effort, I have done some edits above...try this one for me...

Comment: if i remove "cmd", "/c", and then run this i get Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Comment: the following works for me: `new String[]{"cmd", "/c","C:\\m-admin\\app.exe"}`                                                        did u got it running?? if yes do post your solution

Comment: @knurdy you forgot the `.exe` after `soffice` in your answer (well I did as well...)

Comment: even         ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program\\soffice.exe"}); doesnot open my application

Answer (score 0):

Exit status 0 usually means no error.

Try using ProcssBuilder instead.

With ProcessBuilder you can set [the working directory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29).

[Here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738998/how-can-i-start-a-net-application-from-java-on-linux-mac-and-windows/4740783#4740783) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399142/please-clarify-the-issue-in-the-java-code-below/3399186#3399186) [links](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) that might help.

Comment: BTW, if you're trying to launch the app you may also try `Desktop.open()` but I'm not sure if that's what you need.

Comment: i want C:\\Program Files\\OpenOffice.org 3\\program\\ to be my directory when i run soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard

Comment: na actually i am trying to run a service